# Compare the equality of vectors in a std::map

Tags: c++, qt

I am passing a `QString` and two 3D vectors to a `std::map` to compare the vectors with each other and to find the most varying vectors using a given tolerance.

```
std::map<QString, std::pair<Vector3F, Vector3F>> map; // Each Vector3F contains x,y,z
for (; iter != imageInfos.end(); ++iter)
{
  map.insert(std::make_pair(iter->fileName, std::make_pair(iter->vectorX, iter->vectorY)));
}

std::map<QString, std::pair<Vector3F, Vector3F> >::iterator iter;
for (iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); ++iter)
{
  cout << "fileName: " << iter->first.toStdString() << ": " << iter->second.first << " " << iter->second.second << endl;
      
  float diffVectorX = std::fabs(iter->second.first.GetNorm() - boost::prior(iter->second.first.GetNorm())); // compare current vectorX parameters with previous one 
  float diffVectorY = std::fabs(iter->second.second.GetNorm() - boost::prior(iter->second.second.GetNorm())); //compare current vectorY parameters with previous one 
      
  if (diffVectorX < 0.001 || diffVectorY < 0.001)
  {
    cout << "Found "<< endl;
  }
}
    

fileName: c:/im2/IMG001: [0.999927, -9.97105e-05, -0.012124] [9.74977e-05, 1, -0.000179654]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG002: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332457, -0.999927]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG003: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332523, -0.999927]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG004: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332523, -0.999927]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG005: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332457, -0.999927]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG006: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332457, -0.999927]
fileName: c:/im2/IMG007: [-0.0274148, 0.999624, 0] [-0.0121198, -0.000332457, -0.999927]
```

The output above goes through the map and compares each vector with the previous one. But the `if` condition never get fulfilled, although the vectors
`fileName: c:/im2/IMG001: [0.999927, -9.97105e-05, -0.012124] [9.74977e-05, 1, -0.000179654]` mostly varying from the others.

What I actually want to get is that `c:/im2/IMG001` have difficult vector parameters.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Display also `diffVectorX` and `diffVectorY` and you'll see

Comment: While this isn't a [mre], I can observe from the code that _is shown_ that the values that you are passing to `boost::prior` (comparable to `std::prev`) are probably not what you want to pass to it.  `boost::prior` expects an iterator.